# Cypher Http request with match parameters

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I'd like to execute an http cypher query with parameters like :

```
{"statements":
 [
  {"statement":"MATCH path=(p:Person {props})-[*..100]->() RETURN [n in nodes(path)]",
   "parameters":{"props":{"name":"Lucille"}}
  }
 ]
}
```

However i get the following error `Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. \"{id: {param}.id}\")`.

I have no idea how to use a literal map here.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either have:

```
{
  "statements": [{
    "statement": "MATCH path=(p:Person { name: {name} })-[*..100]->() ...",
    "parameters": { "name": "Lucille" }
  }]
}
```

or `MATCH path=(p:Person { name: props.{name} }) ...` while keeping you initial `parameters`

The reason is given in [this comment](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1525#issuecomment-28979448):

> "Unlike properties in CREATE, MATCH requires the map to be a literal. This is because the property names must be known in advance, when the query is compiled, in order to efficiently plan its execution."

Answer (score 1):

I think your query would become:

```
MATCH path=(p:Person {id: {props}.id })-[*..100]->() 
RETURN [n in nodes(path)]
```